# Issue while deletion of item using script on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Environment: Azure PAAS

Activity: Deletion of folders, sub-folders and yml files

As part of our CI-CD process, we delete a folder, sub-folders and yml files. We do this activity in 2 different regions.

The deletion has failed for a set of items in Staging and another set in Production. Surprisingly that has happened only in a particular region (**EU-West**). The remaining objects have got deleted by the same script successfully.

The error logged is for the `Unauthorized access exception`.

We have been able to delete the folder, including its content from the Azure command prompt.
As the folder is inside `D:`, we could not try it from the UI.

Please advice.

Comment: Where are those files?

Comment: @nutsAndBolts try deleting those folders by connecting to [kudu console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session) via ssh(linux app)\cmd(windows based apps).

Comment: @VenkateshDodda: It is part of CI-CD. Cannot do it manually during every run.

Comment: @zolty13: the folder is under D:\home\U1

Comment: @NutsAndBolts why do you have files in PaaS web app file system?

Comment: @zolty13: The folder was to be p[art of CI-CD. Nothing of it was to be used by the running application. Is there any Azure guideline for not using it?

Comment: I do not know what folder you use and why. Could give some example, name? PaaS enable us not to worry about files in web app so usually I do not need to looking there